# Get the last index of a letter followed by numeric

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse a URL and I'd like to test for the last index of a couple characters followed by a numeric value.

Example 
used-cell-phone-albany-m3359_l12201

I'm trying to determine if the last "-m" is followed by a numeric value.

So something like this, "used-cell-phone-albany-m3359_l12201".contains("m" followed by numeric)

I'm assuming it needs to be done with regular expressions, but I'm not for sure.

Comment: are you trying to tell me you couldn't find ANY examples of pattern matching online?

Comment: If I did, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: But what about `_I1`?

Comment: I just need to determine the url type in order to parse it.

Comment: @CodeJunkie, google "java pattern matching", you wont be disappointed.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern like `[a-z]\\d` which searches for any numbers which appear next to a character between `a-z`, you can specify other characters within the group if you wish...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]\\d", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);        
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("used-cell-phone-albany-m3359_l12201");

while (matcher.find()) {

    int startIndex = matcher.start();
    int endIndex = matcher.end();

    String match = matcher.group();

    System.out.println(startIndex + "-" + endIndex + " = " + match);

}
```

The problem is, your test `String` actually contains two matches `m3` and `l1`

The above example will display

```
23-25 = m3
29-31 = l1
```

**Updated with feedback**

If you can guarantee the marker (ie `-m`), then it comes a lot simpler...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-m\\d", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);       
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("used-cell-phone-albany-m3359_l12201");

if (matcher.find()) {

    int startIndex = matcher.start();
    int endIndex = matcher.end();

    String match = matcher.group();

    System.out.println(startIndex + "-" + endIndex + " = " + match);

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, isn't there 1 match? something like -m[0-9] ?

Comment: Can you guarantee that `-m` is the character you are looking for? I thought you were looking for the last character before numbers?  If you can guarantee that `-m` is the terminating your looking for, then it becomes much simpler

Comment: yup, -m is my last character I'm looking for, it's what I used to define the url

Comment: Sure is :) I'll explain it better next time, sorry about that. Anyhow thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also try String#lastIndexOf

Comment: @MadProgrammer just wondering, what if he had something like "used-cell-m3-albany-m256_2435". Doesn't that cause issues. Is there a way to search staring from the end?

Comment: @AlexK Yeah, that's going to cause issues, this is where something like `String#lastIndexOf` might be more useful

Comment: @AlexK This is also where I might use part of the first example and loop till you find the last occurance (my regular expression is pretty basic)

Comment: @Alexk I ended up tweeking the regex to look for the last occurance the regex example provided by Tris example "^.+?-m\\d.*$", but excellent point.

Comment: @CodeJunkie I plugged that regular expression into [Regx Tester](http://regexpal.com/) using `used-cell-m3-albany-m256_2435` and couldn't get it to work, I've not tried testing it with the Java yet.  Lots of ways to skin the cat.  You could, for example, keep looping, cut the `String` into small chunks until no more matches remain...as an idea ;)

Comment: yeah your right, it doesn't seem to be working, well once I detect if it exist, I then split the url up into smaller chunks and do some additional processing. Thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

In Java, convert the URL to a String if necessary and then run

```
URLString.match("^.*m[0-9]+$").
```

Only if that returns true, then the URL ends with "m" followed by a number.  That can be refined with a more precise ending pattern. The reason this regex tests the pattern at the end of the string is because $ in a regex matches the end of the string; "[0-9]+" matches a sequencs of one or more numerical digits; "^" matches the beginning of the string; and ".*" matches zero or more arbitrary but printable characters including white space, letters, numbers and puctuation marks.

To determine if the last "m" is followed by a number then use

```
URLString.match("^.+?m[0-9].*$")
```

Here ".+?" greedily matches all characters up to the very last "m".

Comment: Well these URLs always end in numbers, but the numeric length may very depending on the db's pk which is the reason I can't look backwards. I just want to know if the last character following a the - is an m with the very next character being a digit.

Comment: To determine if the last "m" is followed by a number then use URLString.match("^.+?m[0-9].*$")